# how to use hashed password in impersonate of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, passwords, hash, impersonation

I have an ASP.NET application that requires impersonation as an administrator user. In web.config:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="administrator" password="password"/>
```

The customer complained about saving the password in clear text format. Is there a way to save the password here as hashed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aspnet_regiis with the appropriate switch should do the trick, see [this](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/05/30/encrypting-identities-in-web-config.aspx) article.

Comment: thanks, I also found a windows application that encrypt the config file http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2008/07/29/encrypting-configuration-settings-in-net-2-0.aspx