# Impersonation in ASP.NET without declaring password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement impersonation in ASP.NET. I am following this [URL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158).

Microsoft beautifully explains the process.

However, I am a bit skeptical about declaring the password in web.config

Is there any way, we can achieve impersonation without declaring password?

Thank you

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912903/how-to-use-hashed-password-in-impersonate-of-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: You can try with Mode="Windows" which will impersonate with Integrated security.

Comment: You want any code, on any machine in your organization, to be able to say "I'm really the CEO, trust me", just by placing itself inside an asp.net website?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I got your point. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use user name and password for impersonation you have to store it somewhere.

But here is a list of things you can try:

- Don't store credentials, but ask user to type them in. This will remove maintenance headache from you (user left company, password expired etc)
- Store credentials in [web config using encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213/706456)
- Use Windows impersonation where currently logged in user passes a security descriptor automagically.